# Usage of 'and' to mean both this and that

Tags: articles, conjunctions, ambiguity

A friend of mine occasionally says

> I would like a chocolate and vanilla ice-cream.

In this case he really meant that he would like *a chocolate* and *a vanilla* ice-cream. That makes two ice-creams. I am wondering if this usage is correct as it normally would be written as:

> I would like a chocolate and a vanilla ice-cream.

Answer (score 1):

If I were to hear the first sentence spoken, I would tend to interpret it as

> I would like a chocolate-and-vanilla ice cream.

That is, a scoop of chocolate and a scoop of vanilla served as one cone or bowl, or possibly the two flavors swirled together.

To convey the meaning of two separate ice creams, some better expressions would be

> I would like a chocolate and a vanilla ice cream. *(As you suggested)*
>
> I would like chocolate and vanilla ice creams.
>
> I would like one chocolate ice cream and one vanilla ice cream. *(A very explicit way to disambiguate)*

Comment: Which sentence is more proper: I would like a chocolate and a vanilla ice cream. OR I would like to have a chocolate and a vanilla ice cream?

Comment: So, just to clarify, it is correct to say what my friend has said in that context of meaning having 2 instead of 1 ice-cream?

Comment: @RuchirM Both are fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you aren't looking for corrections, but whether your friend is correct in saying what he said. I'm not sure whether we can say if what your friend said is *correct*, but it **is** ambiguous. I hear people describe things as your friend did often, so it is at least generally used.

Like the previous poster said, though, there are definitely more appropriate, straightforward ways to convey what your friend wants.